# Rewriting cpufreq_frequency_table initialization for legacy cpufreq_driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

long time listener, first time caller.

I've been backporting features from upstream code as recent as 4.12-rc-whatever to a 3.4-base kernel for an older Qualcomm SoC board (apq8064, ridiculous undertaking I know).

Thus far I've been successful in almost every core api, with any compatibility issues solved by creative  shims and ducttape, with the exception of cpufreq.

Keep in mind that I'm still using legacy platform drivers and clocking, no dt's or common clock frame work.

My issue begins with the inclusion of stuct cpufreq_frequency_table into struct cpufreq_policy, as part of the move from percpu to per-policy in the api. In 3.13, registering a platform's freq_table becomes more difficult for unique cases, as using cpufreq_frequency_table_get_attr is no longer an option.

In my case, the cpufreq_driver's init is generic, and relies on my platform's scaling driver (acpuclock-krait) to register the   freq_table, which is fine for the older api, but becomes incompatible with the per-policy setup. The upstream so I requires the driver to manually initialize policy->freq_table and mine uses both a cpu, and an array of 35 representing the tables in the platform code. As well, it accounts for the 6 different speedbin/pvs values when choosing a table. I'm considering either dropping the "cpu" param from it and using cpumask_copy, and perhaps even combining the two drivers into one and making the clock driver a probe, but yeah, thus far init is a mystery for me.  Here is the snippet of my table registration, if anyone can think of something hackable, I'd be eternally grateful...

```
ifdef CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_MSM
static struct     cpufreq_frequency_table.freq_table[NR_CPUS][35];
extern int console_batt_stat;
static void __init cpufreq_table_init(void)
{
    int cpu;
    int freq_cnt = 0;

    for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) {
        int i;
        /* Construct the freq_table tables from     acpu_freq_tbl. */
        for (i = 0, freq_cnt = 0;     drv.acpu_freq_tbl[i].speed.khz != 0
                && freq_cnt <     ARRAY_SIZE(*freq_table)-1; i++) {
            if (drv.acpu_freq_tbl[i].use_for_scaling) {
                freq_table[cpu][freq_cnt].index =     freq_cnt;
                freq_table[cpu][freq_cnt].frequency
                    = drv.acpu_freq_tbl[i].speed.khz;
                freq_cnt++;
            }
        }
        /* freq_table not big enough to store all usable freqs. */
        BUG_ON(drv.acpu_freq_tbl[i].speed.khz != 0);

        freq_table[cpu][freq_cnt].index = freq_cnt;
        freq_table[cpu][freq_cnt].frequency =     CPUFREQ_TABLE_END;

        /* Register table with CPUFreq. */
        cpufreq_frequency_table_get_attr(freq_table[cpu], cpu);
    }

    dev_info(drv.dev, "CPU Frequencies Supported: %d\n", freq_cnt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!!! I wanted to update the initial registration BEFORE merging all the core changes back in, and am pretty certain that I've done so.  Previously, the array in question referenced a percpu dummy array that looked like this:     freq_table[NR_CPUS][35] that required the cpu parameter to be listed as part of the table. I've made some changes here that allows me a percpu setup AND the platform-specific freq management( which cpufreq doesn't need to see), but with a dummy table representing the "index," which cpufreq does need to see. Commit is here, next one fixed obvious mistakes: https://github.com/robcore/machinex/commit/59d7e5307104c2396a2e4c2a5e0b07f950dea10f